# Determining the local intranet ip address in .NET

Tags: .net, ip-address, windows-networking

I am trying to get the local intranet ip of a machine from code running on that machine
Is there a definitive way to do this?

I have tried getting all the IPs and filtering by 
10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255,172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255,192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
```

but this seems a bit magic to me, i'd rather .net did the work, it also returns multiple ips due to me having VirtualBox installed

I have also tried the following

```
var localAddress =
    (
        from ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        where ni.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback
                && hostEntry.HostName.EndsWith(string.Concat(".", ni.Name))
        let props = ni.GetIPProperties()
        from unicastAddress in props.UnicastAddresses
        where unicastAddress.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork
        select unicastAddress.Address).FirstOrDefault();
```

which does work, but would it work on other network configurations?

this bit concerns me `hostEntry.HostName.EndsWith(string.Concat(".", ni.Name))`

Has anyone got a better way?

Comment: We could probably suggest better options if you told us how you're planning to *use* this result. There's no guarantee on what address(es) a particular machine might be using, it may be multi-homed, it may be IPv6 only, etc, so the current "filter by a few ranges, hope to get only one" will never work.

Comment: it will be used by a client on the same network, to connect to that machine using http

Comment: And machine names won't work?

Comment: no, not sure why, the client is not a member of the domain - the local ip works e.g. 192.168.0.22, I can check which ips are v6 and only use them if no v4's exists, its just identifing which is the local intranet ip that I need

Comment: in fact, there may not even be a domain - does that make any difference?

Comment: The point of this is to be able to contact the machine, with any network configuration and any client on the same network... so, if this is not possible then that's an answer too

Comment: Given that a machine can have multiple cards, are you able to make the connection and use the connection to determine which was used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reliably use a single IP as the machine could have multiple network cards or multiple IPs per network card. For example my laptop has both a wired network card and a wireless network card and is quite happy to grab two local IPs from my router via DHCP.

Also in some fancy network setups (mostly corporate environments) you can have IP with different subnets able to talk to each via a router. I might have floor #6 in an office tower be 192.168.6.X and floor number 7 be 192.168.7.X and then have a router allow traffic across multiple subnets despite them being masked apart by the subnet mask.

A better strategy would be to grab the list of local IPs, filter for loopback addresses (127.0.0.1) and then attempt to connect to the target machine.

But if you just want to detect a local IP as "not public on the internet", you can attempt to ping a public address (maybe your webserver?) with a time-to-live (TTL) of 1 hop. This won't make it past any router if one is present, meaning it will fail if it can't reach the public internet in 1 hop or less indicating that it is behind a firewall.

Check out this great answer on stackoverflow which includes source code: [Check if IP is in LAN (behind firewalls and routers)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7232612/1002041)